# Right tools for GUI windows program

Tags: android, python, client-server

I will start a project ( not commercial, just for learning ) but I would like to choose to work with the right tools as I would if I were doing it for a company.

First of all small description of what I will need.
It would be a server-client(s) application.
For the server:
- GUI for Windows
- ORM 
- Database without installation (sqlite ???)
- GUI builder (RAD Tool)
- Ability to create easily REST Services

Clients would be android devices
- GUI for android mobile

Clients would connect to the server and get some initial settings and then start to 
send  information to the server.
Server should be able to display properly the information collected from the clients and 
edit them if needed.

Open source technologies are mandatatory.

First I am thinking to use sqlite ( I should not make any installation except the programm). Any alternatives here?

For the server maybe python with a gui library and sql alchemy. What about Camelot?

And for the clients (android) java. I think there are no other options here.

Can you make some comments on the above choices?
Maybe you can suggest something different which will make the development faster...

Answer (score 3):

> And for the clients (android) java. I think there are no other options here.

I'm no expert in the area, but below are some possible alternatilves for you:

- C#: Mono for Droid (with MonoDevelop?)

  - http://monodevelop.com/Download/Mono_For_Android
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monodroid?sort=votes
- JavaScript: Titanium Appcelerator

  - https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Home
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcelerator?sort=votes
- Python: Kivy

  - http://kivy.org/docs/guide/quickstart.html#quickstart
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+python?sort=votes

For negative opinions on using such rapid-development frameworks, see, eg.

- [Appcelerator vs Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049541/appcelerator-vs-android-sdk)

Of course such problems are not particular to the above frameworks... We couldn't rename a file atomically on Windows until the arrival of JDK7 which finally allows us to use `MoveFileEx()` (cf. [Reliable File.renameTo() alternative on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000183/reliable-file-renameto-alternative-on-windows) ).  But you should always be careful on how to find an escape hatch :-)

Answer (score 0):

As you have asserted: client is java only.

On server:

1. GUI for Windows : WPF
2. ORM - Database without installation : SQLCE 4.0 - Maybe use codefirst
3. GUI builder (RAD Tool) : Visual Studio lets you do that for WPF apps
4. Ability to create easily REST Services : Use WCF

hope that helps

Comment: [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home) is a Python framework for Android applications. I haven't tried it myself, but...not quite 'java only'.